# Do programs have living quarters in Tron?

Tags: tron

Do programs have living quarters?

I see Tron has a hideout similar to Kevin's but what about all the programs in the city?

The ISOs had towers at one point. So do the programs have apartments, or are also crammed into towers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Brian Daley's novelisation of Tron, there's a scene after Tron rescues Yori from the factory which is set in her apartment. The [Tron wikia](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Tron_Wiki) suggests [this was a deleted scene](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Yori) from the theatrical cut.

Comment: In fact, you can view the deleted scene on various DVDs and probably YouTube. It was cut because it was set to be a sex scene, with Yori displaying computerized lingerie. It didn't really add much to the dtory, but it *does* explain the strange jump in story.